# Scrapy link scraped that is empty is ignored

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping links and first level data from this webpage, https://researchgrant.gov.sg/Pages/Search.aspx?keyword=&source=sharepoint&type=project&status=open, for ex: (project title, status, HI name, PI name, Start date) then i will need to scrape the second level data within every link,for ex, the link will bring to https://researchgrant.gov.sg/pages/Awarded-Project-Detail.aspx?AXID=RC/ZRRF/0006/2017&CompanyCode=moh, and combine both data. In some cases, the link scraped in the first page will redirect to the homepage because there is no second level data available for the link scraped. I will need to combine the first level data and second level data for every single data entry. The problem i encounter is when the link doesn't have second level data, the first level data will also not be shown. Meaning that the whole entry is ignored even though there is first level data. How do i show first level data even though there is no second level data?

Scrapy coding:

```
class ToScrapeCSSSpiderSG(scrapy.Spider):
name = "toscrapesg-css"= {
    'name':'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }  
args = {
        'keyword': '',
        'source': 'sharepoint',
        'type': 'project',
        'status': 'open',
        'page': 1,
        '_pp_projectstatus': 'Closed',
        '_pp_hiname': 'ab',
        '_pp_piname': '',
        '_pp_source': '',
        '_pp_details': '',
        'name':'advancesearchawardedprojectsp'
    }
def start_requests(self):
    args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)
    url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,callback=self.parse_item,method='POST',formdata=self.params,headers = {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'})


def parse_item(self,response):
    for row in response.xpath('//table[@name="MVCGridTable_advancesearchawardedprojectsp"]/tbody/tr'):
        #scrape first level data
        link=row.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
        projectTitle=row.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
        status = row.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()
        hostInstitution = row.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').get()
        principalInvestigator = row.xpath('.//td[4]/text()').get()
        startDate = row.xpath('.//td[5]/text()').get()  

        projectTitle = projectTitle.strip()
        status = status.strip()
        hostInstitution = hostInstitution.strip()
        principalInvestigator = principalInvestigator.strip()
        startDate = startDate.strip()
        #pass the data to 2nd level data scraping function
        yield scrapy.Request(link,callback = self.parse_product,meta={'item':projectTitle})

    onclick = response.xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next page"]/@onclick').get()
    if onclick:
        self.args['page'] += 1
        args = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.args)
        url = 'https://researchgrant.gov.sg/eservices/mvcgrid?' + args
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_item, method='POST', formdata=self.params, headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

def parse_product(self,response):
        projectID = response.xpath('//span[contains(@id,"ctl00_ctl47_g_b43c0a74_fae0_498f_b75e_c103772db011_ctl00_lblProjIdExt")]/text()').get()
        print(projectID + response.meta["item"])
```

for ex: there are 15 links to be scraped in `parse_item`, 
[image]

and when calling Request, only 6 links have second level `parse_product` data and is shown, the first 7 links that are redirected to homepage will be ignored.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright got the answer, if the link to be scraped is unavailable, it will redirect to the homepage as stated in the question, just add `meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]}` at the Scrapy.Request and it will ignore the redirect and return 'none' for the data to be scraped.

Comment: Actually I think `handle_httpstatus_list` is not necessary here; just disabling redirects should do it.

Comment: in my case it is still needed because after removing, it will ignore those links

Comment: shouldn't these links _be_ ignored? Unless the website is misconfigured it shouldn't return any content on `302` so parsing it is redundant.